# Identifying good areas in a two dimensional graph

Tags: r, spatial

I have a an outcome variable with three states: win(green), lose(red) and draw(gray) and a sample of data points, each with a value on two independent variables x and y.

I can plot the outcomes using the x and y variables as coordinates in a two dimensional plane, like this:

(the points are partly transparent, so brown points are two points one green and an one red overlayed)

[image]

Now to the problem, while I can by visual inspection and some intutition find candidate areas which might be better than others in the sense that probability of win is higher and probability of losing is lower in those areas, and the circle is my try, but is there a statistical method that could do a better job? If so, which do you recommend?

What I wish of the method is for it to say if there are one or more areas which are significantly better than others, and if so, which these areas are.

I prefer r-code, but am willing to try whatever you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a classification problem with two dimensions, and there are a lot of tools for this problem. A simple one is [k-nearest neighbors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).

If you need R code, you can Google for it, but [this post in R bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/k-nearest-neighbor-step-by-step-tutorial/) may be useful, or you can use section 4.6.5 of [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @Pere for classifying my problem as a classification problem :-) and for the links!